# About the plugin "EventBrite" with the new version Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, events, plugins

These days I want to have a plugin for online bus tickets selling.
Then I found the "EventBrite" plugin.
But it doesn't work after I installed the Events Calendar plugin.
I noticed that it said the plugin only works for the PHP ver5.1 !
I used WAMP as the develop environment and the PHP version is 5.3.5, after I changed the version to 5.1.0. The system said it doesn't compatiable with my Apache version.
After I installed the plugin with PHP 5.3.5 and a new wordpress website.
It just give me an FAtal Error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_version() in
>   C:\wamp\www\TE\wp-content\plugins\eventbrite-for-the-events-calendar\eventbrite-for-the-events-calendar.class.php
>   on line 88

How can I solve this problem. And does any people using this plugin with php new version?
Could you give me some other plugins to do this task?
I'm just new here. Thanks for all and hoping for good news !

Answer (score 1):

try using the event [espresso plugin](http://eventespresso.com/) instead. A much better option in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Tested this with PHP 5.3.3.  Works fine once you get php5-curl enabled.

Comment: Please add a comment to your answer, or edit your answer.  Please don't create a new answer.